# "could not obtain access token" error in spring security oauth2

Tags: spring, oauth

In my spring project i have an oauth2 client app running on localhost:9999 and an oauth2 authorization server running on localhost:8080.
In result, after approval page, i see error page that i don't know what is the problem?
when press F12 i see that set-cookie done! but /oauth/token not called! and /me also not called! and browser not redirect to localhost:9999.

my client app

```
package sso.client;
import java.security.Principal;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class App {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home(Principal user) {
    return "Hello " + user.getName();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class)
        .properties("spring.config.name=client").run(args);
  }

}
```

client.yml

```
server:
  port: 9999
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: acme
      client-secret: acmesecret
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:8080/me
```

my authorization server

```
package sso.raymon;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@EnableWebSecurity
public class App extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
     }

     @Configuration
     @EnableAuthorizationServer
     protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

          @Autowired
          private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


          @Override
          public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
               endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
          }

          @Override
            public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)
                    throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
            }

          @Override
          public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
               // @formatter:off
               clients.inMemory()
               .withClient("acme")
               .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
               .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
               .scopes("read", "write")
               .secret("acmesecret");
               // @formatter:on
          } 
     }
     @RequestMapping("/me") 
     public String home(Principal user) {
          return user.getName();
     }

     @Configuration
     @EnableResourceServer 
     protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

          @Override 
          public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
              http
                    .antMatcher("/me")
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
          }

     }
}
```

application.properties

```
security.user.name=forough
security.user.password=m123
```

Error in blow URL:

> localhost:9999/login?code=xZgYwZ&state=27XzVY

Error:

> Whitelable Error Page
>   this application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this a fallback.
>   There was an unexpected erroe (type=Unauthorized, atatus=401).
>   Authentication Failed: could not obtain access token

Comment: I use custom tokenStore, met the same err. Have you resolved it ?

Comment: I get the same only when running the client as Docker container.

Comment: Just ran into this today too, but only in Docker. Did any of y'all figure it out?

Comment: I have the same issue. Not sure if it's because of the app running in Docker container (mine is)

Comment: @MattRaible how did you resolve this problem? I am also stuff in this problem since few days.